# Understanding Spring transactions - What happens when a transactional method calls another transactional method?

Tags: java, spring, transactions

Just to understand the workings of Spring transactions I want to know what happens in the following case where one method marked as `@Transactional` calls another method marked as `@Transactional`.

Assume a the configuration uses all default settings.

```
@Service("myService")
@Transactional
public MyService{
   public void myServiceMethod(){
      myDAO.getSomeDBObjects();
   }
}

@Repository("myDAO")
@Transactional
public MyDAOWithUsesBeyondMyService{
   public void getSomeDBObjects(){...}
}
```

Now if I were to enter `MyService.myServiceMethod()` it would clearly start a transaction. Then, upon drilling into `myDAO.getSomeDBObjects()` what would happen? Would the fact that a transaction already exist cause no new transaction to be born, or am I creating two transactions here?

The documentation (quoted below) on Propagation seems to cover this, but I'd like to verify my understanding, it was a little much for my virgin brain to comprehend all at once.

> **Propagation**: Typically, all code
>   executed within a transaction scope
>   will run in that transaction. However,
>   you have the option of specifying the
>   behavior in the event that a
>   transactional method is executed when
>   a transaction context already exists.
>   For example, code can continue running
>   in the existing transaction (the
>   common case); or the existing
>   transaction can be suspended and a new
>   transaction created. Spring offers all
>   of the transaction propagation options
>   familiar from EJB CMT. To read about
>   the semantics of transaction
>   propagation in Spring, see Section
>   10.5.7, “Transaction propagation”.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Two answers:

a) don't do it. Use `@Transactional` in the service layer or the dao layer, but not both (the service layer is the usual choice, as you probably want one transaction per service method)

b) if you do it, what happens depends on the `propagation` attribute of the `@Transactional` annotation and is described in this section: [10.5.7 Transaction propagation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-propagation). Basically: `PROPAGATION_REQUIRED` means the same transaction will be used for both methods, while `PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW` starts a new transaction.

**About your comments:**

> Of course I kept reading and realized that, as I'm using proxies, this second method won't be managed by the transactional proxy, thus it's like any other method call.

That's not true in your situation (only if both methods were within the same class).

If a bean has methods `a` and `b`, and `a` calls `b`, then `b` is called on the actual method, not the proxy, because it is called from within the proxy (a bean doesn't know that it is proxied to the outside world).

```
proxy      bean  
a() -->    a()
            |
            V  
b() -->    b()
```

In your situation, however, a service would have an injected dao object, which would be a proxy itself, so you'd have a situation like this:

```
           proxy      bean
service    a() -->    a()
                       |
             /---------/
             |                 
             V
dao        b() -->    b()
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, I don't intend on doing this, but the question popped to mind when I realized that I had declared @Transactional at a service class level, and one method of the service was calling another method of the service (both transactional). Of course I kept reading and realized that, as I'm using proxies, this second method won't be managed by the transactional proxy, thus it's like any other method call (that's enough to confound a newly initiated brain). :)  But it made me curious enough to ensure I understood the details of how it all works, you've clarified that for me well. Thanks!

Comment: @David I think you misunderstood the proxy concept a bit. Read my update.

Comment: You're absolutely correct, my comment was in error (actually I switched assumptions without saying so), but I understand what you're saying, and after all of that I think the whole thing is well rooted in my head now. Thanks for the update and the great diagrams, I'm sure many others will find it useful in their searches in the future!

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd Can you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31784818/why-transaction-here-is-treated-as-two-separate-transactions and provide your expert advice?